# Query against a pivot column in a Bookshelf belongsToMany call

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js

I have two tables w/ a many to many relationship expressed like:

Table `as`:

```
{
  id: <primary key>
}
```

Table `bs`:

```
{
  id: <primary key>
}
```

Table `as_bs`:

```
{
  as_id: <reference to table as>
  bs_id: <reference to table bs>
  c: <integer column>
}
```

Is is possible to perform a `withRelated` call in bookshelf using a query object that specifies a condition for column `c` in `as_bs`?

Something along the lines of

```
viewRelation: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(bs).withPivot(["c"]).query({where: {c: 1000}});
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided!